# CakePHP: Problemas com rota e paginação

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2, cakephp-3

Estou com um problema com as rotas do `CakePHP`.

Tenho a seguinte URL: *http://www.nomedosite.com.br/Produtos/index/61/789/*
E funciona normalmente. O problema é quando vou para a segunda página: *http://www.nomedosite.com.br/Produtos/index/61/789/page:2*

```
Error: The requested address '/Produtos/index/61/789/page:2' was not found on this server.
```

Inseri uma entrada de configuração no **Config/routes.php**, mas não funcionou.

```php
Router::connect(
    '/Produtos/index/:cat/:id/page:page', 
    [
        'controller' => 'Produtos',
        'action' => 'index'
    ],
    [
        'pass' => ['id', 'cat', 'page'],
        'id' => '[0-9]+',
        'cat' => '[0-9]+',
        'page' => '[0-9]+'
    ]
);
```

Podem me auxiliar?

Answer (score 0):

Modifique  **page:page**  para **:page**

```
Router::connect(
    '/Produtos/index/:cat/:id/:page', 
    [
        'controller' => 'Produtos',
        'action' => 'index'
    ],
    [
        'pass' => ['id', 'cat', 'page'],
        'id' => '[0-9]+',
        'cat' => '[0-9]+',
        'page' => '[0-9]+'
    ]
);
```

Obs. Testei no CakePhp 2x